# Tumblr scraping bot not getting images (scrapy)

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to make a simpe tumblr bot to scrape all the images of a tumblr blog. Right now the spider finds stuff like avatars and icons but not the posts them selves.

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'tumblr'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['tumblr.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tumblr.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures'
```

items.py

```
import scrapy

class TumblrItem(scrapy.Item):

   image_urls = scrapy.Field()
   images = scrapy.Field()
```

tumblr_spider

```
import scrapy

from urlparse import urljoin
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from tumblr.items import TumblrItem

class TumblrSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'tumblr'
    allowed_domains = ['tumblr.com','http://lovedota2.tumblr.com/']
    start_urls =  ['http://lovedota2.tumblr.com/','http://lovedota2.tumblr.com/archive']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/post']), 'parse_tumblr')]

    def parse_tumblr(self, response):
        image = TumblrItem()

        rel = response.xpath("//img/@src").extract()
        image['image_urls'] = [urljoin(response.url, rel[0])]
        return image
```

Any ideas?

Comment: scraping is against point 7 of their ToS: https://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/terms-of-service

Comment: Oh, well. This is all theoretical then. I just want to know what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you are always getting the first image and storing only that one inside a list (so a list with only one element), this is what this line says:

```
image['image_urls'] = [urljoin(response.url, rel[0])]
```

you should maybe use a better xpath to extract the right information, maybe something like:

```
img_xpath = 'id("content")//div[@class="copy"]//img/@src'
image['image_urls'] = response.xpath(img_xpath).extract()
return image
```

This is just an example, you should check if that is the correct xpath